# Would it be possible to point a number of cloudfront distributions to a single s3 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

The intended goal would be to overcome issues where browsers will only download a certain number of files from one domain at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use single S3 bucket as an origin for multiple distributions.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create any number of CloudFront distributions against the same S3 bucket. This can circumvent the limitation of number of open connections a client can have open at the same time (assuming that is your problem)